# Can you name some techniques for feature construction that are better than ngram in text analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, feature-engineering

I have seen in several papers related to text analysis such as :

> Predicting Vulnerable Software Components through N-gram Analysis and
>   Statistical Feature Selection  2015 The Effect of Dimensionality
>   Reduction on Software Vulnerability Prediction Models 2017

that they used `ngram` for feature construction. 
What other choices do we have instead of using ngram that would be a better choice for feature construction in  this regard ?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some kind of basic feature selection would help certainly. You can select for the most important n-grams (uni- to whatever you want), e.g., with $\chi^2$ selection.

A bit "deeper" approach is to detect collocations on an associated corpus, or chunking noun- and, possibly verb-phrases, and use those only those collocations/chunks, instead of working over *all* n-grams. A similar approach generating even less features is to extract keywords, e.g., with the TextRank keyword extraction algorithm.

Finally, keywords can be further enriched again by adding entities from Named Entity Recognition taggers or even joining entities and keywords with dependencies.

As you see, there are plenty of options; the real question is how far you are willing to go or technically can go, in terms of NLP-wise pre-processing of your texts (PoS tagging, phrase chunking, NER tagging, or even dependency parsing for some very complex features).